# splitting citations between main text and supplementary materials

Tags: bibliographies, journal-publishing, amsrefs

I have a strange problem. I am submitting a manuscript but only 20 citations are permitted in the main paper. Any additional citations need to occur in the supplementary materials.

It seems that amsrefs might be suitable as a solution. I would run BibTeX as per  normal and then coble the two reference lists together separately using the amsrefs package like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[initials]{amsrefs}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

A little story about citations \cite{ab, bgv} that need to be in supplementary materials even though they are cited in the main text \cite{botttu,bourbakilie}.

\section{References}

\begin{biblist}[\normalsize]

\bib{ab}{article}{
      author={Atiyah, Michael~F.},
      author={Bott, Raoul},
       title={The moment map and equivariant cohomology},
        date={1984},
     journal={Topology},
      volume={23},
      number={1},
       pages={1\ndash 28},
}

\bib{bgv}{book}{
      author={Berline, Nicole},
      author={Getzler, Ezra},
      author={Vergne, Mich{\`e}le},
       title={Heat Kernels and {D}irac Operators},
      series={Grundlehren Text Editions},
   publisher={Springer-Verlag},
     address={Berlin},
        date={2004},
        ISBN={3-540-20062-2},
        note={Corrected reprint of the 1992 original},
      review={\MR{2273508 (2007m:58033)}},
}

\end{biblist}

\section{More References}

\begin{biblist}[\normalsize\setcounter{bib}{2}]

\bib{botttu}{book}{
      author={Bott, Raoul},
      author={Tu, Loring~W.},
       title={Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology},
   publisher={Springer},
        date={1982},
}

\bib{bourbakilie}{book}{
      author={Bourbaki, N.},
       title={Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, Chapters 4--6},
   publisher={Springer},
        date={2002},
}

\end{biblist}

\end{document}
```

Now, my question: can I instruct LaTeX to represent the references from the second list as [S??] as list them as [S??] in the reference list?

I have tried using

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{[S#1.]}
\makeatother
```

at the start of the 2nd reference list without any success.

Comment: Hello, in the mean time I have found that editing \begin{biblist} for the second set of references like so: \begin{biblist}*{prefix={S}} solves the [S??] issue. I now wonder if it is possible to have author-year (as per natbib \citet{}) in the same document as numerical listings (as per natbib \citep{}). In the above minimal example I have tried \ocite, \ycite and  \citeauthor but haven't got it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your supplementary bibliography, use

```
\begin{biblist*}[\normalsize]*{prefix={S\#}}

   \bib{...}{...}{
      ...
   }

\end{biblist*}
```

---

From Section 3 *The* `biblist` *and* `biblist*` *environments* of the [package documentation](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf):

> The `biblist` environment also takes a second optional argument that can be used to modify the current bibliography. This argument consists of an asterisk followed by a set of key-value pairs surrounded by braces:
>
> ```
> \begin{biblist}*{key={val},...}
> ```
>
> Two keys are supported at present:
> **labels:** Set this to "numeric," "alphabetic," or "shortalphabetic" to override the default label style for the current bibliography.
> **prefix:** The value  of this key will be prepended to each of the labels in the current bibliography.
> **Note:** Neither of these can be used with the `author-year` option.
> For example, if you are using numeric labels, then
>
> ```
> \begin{biblist}*{prefix={A}}
> ```
>
> will cause the items to be labeled "A1," "A2," etc.

I notice that you're also using the optional argument `\normalsize` in your MCVE. Here's what the documentation has to say about that:

> If you want to use both types of optional arguments, the key-value pairs come second:
>
> ```
> \begin{biblist}[\normalsize]*{...}
> ```

I also notice that you're using the optional argument `\setcounter{bib}{2}` for your supplementary bibliography so that the numbering continues from where you left off. Rather than doing this by hand, there is a simpler option as mentioned in the documentation:

> Each `biblist` environment resets the `bib` counter so that its items are numbered starting from 1. If you want the numbering to start where the last `biblist` left off, use the `biblist*` environment instead.

I also notice that you're using `\section{References}` before the first set of references in `\begin{biblist} ... \end{biblist}` and `\section{More References}` before the second set. Instead, consider wrapping the `biblist` environment between `\begin{bibdiv}` and `end{bibdiv}`. This will print `References` for you as a section title (but without any numbering, which is to be preferred).

To change the words that are printed, you can redefine the command `\refname`; for instance, you can add `\renewcommand{\refname}{More References}` before wrapping the second set of references within the `bibdiv` environment. See Section 4 *Section titles for bibliographies:* `bibdiv`*,* `bibsection`*,* `bibchapter` of the package documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful.

Comment: @Tyrone Happy to have helped :) Regarding your question in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358354/splitting-citations-between-main-text-and-supplementary-materials/601284#comment883294_358354) under the question, I am fairly sure that the answer is, no, it is not possible to have both, [author-year] as well as [numerical] citations, in the same document. For instance, as mentioned in the first quote in my answer, the documentation says that the key-value option `*label={numeric}` cannot be used with the `author-year` option.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am used to be spoilt with Natbib where I can call \citep or \citet and get what I want. With the more and more journals forcing content into supplementary materials, I hope some computer-savvy LaTeX fan will build a solution.